# Single word for a move in an argument

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing a piece about how each move in a particular debate functions rhetorically, and I'd like to introduce my recap at the end of the piece as follows:

> Because the debate is complex, it behooves us to recap the function of
>   each **move**.

Is there a better word than "move"? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The word **move** itself can indeed be used, though some rephrasing is needed. Instead of

> Because the debate is complex, it behooves us to recap the function of each move.

let's go with:

> The complexity of the debate behooves us to provide a recap for every move made by each candidate.

I personally think **move** is a bit too vague and all-encompassing. Something more specific like **argument**, statement, or **response** is more apt.

Comment: "Argument" was the first thing that occurred to me.

Answer (score 2):

Kris and Vth are both correct up to a point.  *rhetorical move* is used in this way.  However, there is an ambiguity involved:  an ambiguity between *type* and *token*.

For example, in chess, we can speak of a *bishop’s move* (a **type** of move) and also of a player’s *opening move* or *6th move*.

So in chess we might say that someone’s 6th move was clever or a fatal mistake. But we cannot make that sort of judgement about *castling* or  *pawn sacrifice*, because it would depend on the state of the game at the time.

Similarly in rhetoric, a *move* might mean a *type of* move, such as anaphora, rhetorical question or exclamation.  But it might also mean a particular move.  Imagine I say “Does anyone here imagine that the world is no more than a few thousand years old?”.  Whether this is a good or bad ‘move’ must depend on the audience:  if it consists of earth scientists, it is pointless; if of creationists, it is ill-advised as well as pointless.

So there is an ambiguity worth avoiding.  As it happens, there is a word that univocally refers to **types** of ‘move’, which is used by students of rhetoric.  Books on the subject speak of ***rhetorical devices***.  This is what I suggest, so that the word ‘move’ can be reserved for a particular deployment of such a device.

Answer (score 0):

Within the domain, it's simply referred to as a *move* most of the time, since the reader is expected to be familiar with structure.

However, in the OP's context, it is appropriate to use the full phrase *rhetorical move*:  "... to recap the function of each **rhetorical move**."